# I get 429 status code for microsoft.web/serverFarms when I create function App on azure

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cloud-services, server-farm

I have azure functions developed in node js. When I create a cloud instance for function app, it gets stuck on deployment process with all the resources OK status. **Microsoft.Web/serverfarms** returning 429. The error message reads as:

```
**"status"**: "Failed",
**"error"**: {
**"code"**: "429",
**"message"**: "App Service Plan Create operation is throttled for subscription <subcription_id>. Please contact support if issue persists.",
}
```

Please let me know what the possible solution will be for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, you just need to create a new function application with different  server location. and delete all the related instances of the previously deployed azure function.